# Problem with .Net Image processing on Windows Server 2003

Tags: .net, image-processing, windows-server-2003

In asp.net 2.0 application I am trying to create thumbnails from uploaded images. However when I test the application on my PC under Windows7 it works fine, but on the real Windows 2003 Server the resized image has worse quality.

Where this difference could come from? Different JPEG codec or what, if Yes how it can be updated on Win 2003 Server? Thanks!

Here is the code:

**Resize of the Image**:

> Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
>   newBmp.SetResolution(inputBmp.HorizontalResolution,
>   inputBmp.VerticalResolution);
>
> //Create a graphics object attached to
>   the new bitmap Graphics newBmpGraphics
>   = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp);
>
> newBmpGraphics.InterpolationMode =
>   InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
>
> newBmpGraphics.SmoothingMode =
>   SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
>
> newBmpGraphics.PixelOffsetMode =
>   PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
>
> newBmpGraphics.DrawImage(inputBmp, new
>   Rectangle(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight),
>   new Rectangle(0, 0, inputBmp.Width,
>   inputBmp.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

**Save of the Image**:

> System.IO.Stream imgStream = new
>   System.IO.MemoryStream();
>
> //Get the ImageCodecInfo for the
>   desired target format ImageCodecInfo
>   destCodec =
>   FindCodecForType(ImageMimeTypes.JPEG);
>
> if (destCodec == null) {
>       //No codec available for that format
>       throw new ArgumentException("The requested format image/jpeg does not
>   have an available codec installed",
>   "destFormat"); }
>
> //Create an EncoderParameters
>   collection to contain the //parameters
>   that control the dest format's encoder
>   EncoderParameters destEncParams = new
>   EncoderParameters(1);
>
> EncoderParameter qualityParam = new
>   EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality,(long)quality);
>
> destEncParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
>
> //Save w/ the selected codec and
>   encoder parameters
>   inputBmp.Save(imgStream, destCodec,
>   destEncParams);
>
> Bitmap destBitmap = new
>   Bitmap(imgStream);

Comment: Jpegs will always have bad quality by default in .NET, use PNG for thumbnails instead.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is why the jpeg quality is different on the different OS? Should be the codec..